# Calculations in Recycler View Adapter, Will it affect performance?

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

My doubt is will there be *a low performance* if we **perform calculations before setting data in the recycler view** in Android?

For example, Im receiving list of data as a server response such as:

- Sales target:50 and Sales target achieved:10 for Person A
- Sales Target:60 and Sales Target Achieved:15 for Person B,etc..

and I have to show this in a recycler view along with Percentage, 
So I do a calculation at Android side to **convert these sales target into percentage before setting in the adapter**. So before setting the first data, I calculate percentage by doing this: (10/50) *100, which gives me 20%,and so on, for all the list data. So does this calculation lower the performance of loading in Android or will it be better if I calculate the percentage in the server side and get the percentage in the response itself so that I can simply set it without any calculation, but will it affect response time?

So I'm in a confusion between Server Response Time and Android Processing time.

Answer (score 1):

The percentage seems to be not security-sensitive, you could calculate it on client side. If you want to save time on processing the data, try fill some data to the recycler view's adapter to make it visible to user, then perform some asynchronous 
 background task to calculate the data and update the view.

Comment: Yeah, Async Task seems to be good, I didn't think of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use AsyncTask. It will do task in background thread and will update the UI accordingly.
Below is a simple example:

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
 protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
     int count = urls.length;
     long totalSize = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
         totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
         publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
         // Escape early if cancel() is called
         if (isCancelled()) break;
     }
     return totalSize;
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
 }
}
```

To run AsyncTask

```
new DownloadFilesTask(). execute(param1, param2, param3);
```

To cancel task call

```
cancel();
```